# Rails create mysql views or virtual table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

i'm currently trying to find a way how to get data from database as AREL object, which would be easy to paginate.

From database perspective i see that i need to create mysql insertable/updatable view. Since i have two different tables with different column names. Also i don't need all data only some columns.

I'm curious is there a way to do this without mysql views. Just using Active Record

example

```
 | table1: |
 | id, name, desc, quality | 
 | 1,  t1,   d1,   q1 |
 | 2,  t2,   d2,   q2 |

 | table2: |
 | id, title, description, etc |
 | 1,  p1,    desc1,       null|
 | 2.  p2,    desc2,       null|
```

I want receive somethig like

```
 | JoinTabe |
 | id, col1, col2 |
 | 1,  t1,   d1   |
 | 1,  p1,   desc1|
 | 2,  t2,   d2   |
 | 2,  p2,   desc2|
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a Union.  I believe they have removed the `.union` function from ActiveRecord a long time back because Unions are evil and you shouldn't do Unions.

However, if you want to do a Union, which you shouldn't do, you should use the [select_all](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#select-all) function and pass in the SQL statement that does the Union, which you shouldn't ever do.